# Google API client compatibility with Google Chrome extensions

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working inside of a Google Chrome extension and I would like to use Google's Client API,  https://apis.google.com/js/client.js, to retrieve a user's Google+ ID.

I've supplied the following values in my manifest.json:

```
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "[CLIENT ID].apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
    ]
}
```

Providing these values allows me to successfully call chrome.identity.getAuthToken: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity.html

```
getAuthToken: function () {
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
        interactive: false
    }, function (authToken) {

        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            //  User isn't signed into Google Chrome.
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Once I have an auth token, I'm able to issue an AJAX request and successfully get my info:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("Received user info", response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

None of this uses the aforementioned Google Client API, though. It would be nice to leverage that instead, but I'm wondering if it is not meant for Google Chrome extensions. I'm able to at least get things sort of working like so:

```
GoogleAPI.auth.authorize({
    client_id: '[CLIENT ID].apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
    //  Set immediate to false if authResult returns null
    immediate: true
}, function(){
    GoogleAPI.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {

     var request = GoogleAPI.client.plus.people.get({
        'userId': 'me'
     });

     request.execute(function (response) {
        console.log("Response:", response);
     });
});
```

But I've already specified these values in my manifest -- so it seems a bit odd to re-refrence them. I could load my manifest and parse it, but I've already got something successfully working above.

Additionally, you have to call  GoogleAPI.client.setApiKey to use Google's stuff. This works on a development environment because I am able to whitelist my machine's IP, but this would not work in a production environment as there will be many clients connecting.

So, should Google's Client API not be used within Google Chrome extensions?

Comment: Stared it. I just switched to chrome.identity and am also having to use the http protocol.